# AWS KMS Policy implicitly allows cross-account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms, aws-policies

It seems that **KMS key policies implicitly allow public access to services**.
My setup is as follows:

| Account A (my account) | Account B (external Account) |
| --- | --- |
| KMS key, customer-managed | SNS Topic |
| SQS Queue, encrypted |  |

The SQS-Queue subscribes to the SNS topic. Pretty basic stuff.

The **KMS key policy** allows Account A, the SNS service, and the SQS service to use this key:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[AccountA]:root"},
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": ["kms:*"],
        "Resource": "*"
    },{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "sqs.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": ["kms:*"],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

The SNS topic is granted access to the the SQS Queue via the **queue's Resource Policy**:

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"},
   "Action": "sqs:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:[region]:[AccountA]:sqs-queue-a",
   "Condition": {"ArnEquals": {"aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:[region]:[AccountB]:sns-topic-b"}}
}
```

Here comes the twist: **This works**. Wait, but we never allowed Account B to use the KMS key. Usually I'm glad when things work. But from a security perspective I'm a bit concerned. My question is:

**Why has the Account B SNS-Topic access to the KMS key of Account A, without ever mentioning Account B in the KMS key policy?**

The additional security layer in this particular case is the queue's resource policy, so that's fine. But just from the KMS key policy, every AWS account can now use my key, when using SNS or SQS. I thought, AWS policies implicitly deny calls from other accounts. But it seems that `"Principal": {"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"}` makes the key available to public?

A follow-up question would be: **How can I restrict KMS access to specific accounts?**
My first try was this constraint in the KMS key policy:

```
    },{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": ["kms:*"],
        "Resource": "*"
        "Condition": {"ArnEquals": {"aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:[region]:[AccountB]:sns-topic-b"}}
    },{
```

However, [AWS makes it clear](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/policy-conditions.html#conditions-aws) that the conditions `aws:SourceAccount` and `aws:SourceArn` do not work in KMS policies.

Thanks for reading! I appreciate every help <3

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50756932/2442804 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66075198/2442804 . And no, the key is not "public". I would argue that you allow sqs in account A to do whatever with the key and when sns pushes the message to the queue sqs is actually the one encrypting the data from within your account A, account B does not need specific KMS permissions for it. If on the other hand you were to e.g. create an encrypted queue in account B with the key from account A then the SendMessage operations should fail because sqs in account B is not actually allowed to use the key.